# Telegram BOT API: how to change a photo (not the caption)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I know that common messages, sent via

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

can be edited in all the parts using

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext

The problem I have is related to when sending an image with a text attached; in these cases I used

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

When user interacts with the bot using the "inline_keyboard" I provided, Telegram send me a callback and in some case I need to 'replace' the message entirely.

I used

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagecaption

And this works because I can remove old text, show the new one and remove the keyboard.

The problem is that `editmessagecapition` do no allow me to change the picture! I need, exactly, to *remove it* from the message.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

replacing media is new feature for **users** in last version of telegram. this feature is not present for bot til now.

**Update:** in bot API 4.0 that present yesterday, you can replace media with `editMessageMedia` method.